# ASP.NET Core Web Application with .NET Framework, I want to switch the target to .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-4.8

I'm trying to change ASP.NET Core web application with .NET Framework as a target framework to use .NET Core 3.1.X

I try changing the target framework in the project file (`.csproj`), I  encounter dependency issues, dependency conflict....

Is there any straightforward method to solve this issue?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. What I'd do is just create a new ASP.NET Core web application from the template, then study the .csproj and how it does configuration, and adapt my existing app to follow the new way of doing things.

Comment: my solution consist of 7 class library projects all targeting .NET Framework and One MVC Web Project Also Targeting .NET Framework , are you aware of any tool that can do it automatically

Comment: No, and asking for tools isn't what Stack Overflow is for. Porting the class libraries should be very easy. The MVC project will require more work. Keep in mind that .NET Core 3.1 support ends this year, so you really should be aiming for .NET 6 or .NET 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you start your migration, you should know there’s several difference between .net framework and .net core, so please follow [the official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/third-party-deps) to do some Pre-Migration steps.
Then you can follow [this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/mvc?source=recommendations&view=aspnetcore-7.0) to migrate your application from framework to .net core 3.1.
Since your ideal .net core version is 3.1, still I suggest you can try to use .net 6. Also, you can use [this upgrade tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/upgrade-assistant-overview) to reach your goal. In fact, using this upgrade assistant is a batter choice than you doing it by yourself. Even if you are insisting using .net core 3.1, you can use this assistant to upgrade your version to 6 first then change it to 3.1.

Note:
Before you start your migration, please make a backup of your original project. That's because some packages in .net framework may be no longer available in .net  core. So if there're some errors occur, you can go back to the original one.